# How can I generate pem file for push notifications in iphone?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

Using this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) for generate pem file for push notification, but I can't understand following steps...

> **Installing the SSL Certificate and Key on the Server**
>
> You should install the SSL distribution certificate and private
>   cryptographic key you obtained earlier on the server computer on which
>   the provider code runs and from which it connects with the sandbox or
>   production versions of APNs. To do so, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Open Keychain Access utility and click the My Certificates category in the left pane.
> 2. Find the certificate you want to install and disclose its contents.
>      You'll see both a certificate and a private key.
> 3. Select both the certificate and key, choose File > Export Items, and export them as a Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file.
> 4. Servers implemented in languages such as Ruby and Perl often are better able to deal with certificates in the Personal Information
>      Exchange format. To convert the certificate to this format, complete
>      the following steps:
>
>    - In KeyChain Access, select the certificate and choose File > Export Items. Select the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) option,
>        select a save location, and click Save.
>    - Launch the Terminal application and enter the following command after the prompt: openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out
>        CertificateName.pem -nodes.
> 5. Copy the .pem certificate to the new computer and install it in the appropriate place.

Comment: which two certificate are seleceted in step 3 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

finally i sloved generate push notification certifcates

complete step for generate push notification certificates.....

1) open key chain and request certificate show in below image.

[image]

2) change common name as your project_name.

[image]

3) in keychain open key you can show two key public and private

[image]

4) write click on private key and export it.

[image]

5) make name project_name_key.p12

6) add password ex-1234

7) enter system login password and save it. now you have following certificates.

[image]

8) now goto developer account (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and goto identifier create new if not exits. and edit setting.

[image]
[image]

if push notification disable then enable it from edit.

[image]

9) for development you can create first one and distribution you can select last one.

[image]
[image]

10) after select  and generate download apns certificate and put into desktop and double click on it.

11) then open key chain and goto certificates. and you can show your push service open then you show private key.

export it with 1234 password.

[image]

12) now you have following file.

[image]

13) open terminal and goto desktop.

[image]

14) generate .pem file using following line for push_cert.p12 file

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in push_cert.p12
```

then enter password:-1234

[image]

15) generate .pem file using following line for project_name_key.p12 file

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out apns-dev-key.pem -in project_name_key.p12
```

then enter password:-1234
Enter PEM pass phrase:1234
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:1234

[image]

16) enter following 3 line in terminal

```
openssl rsa -in apns-dev-key.pem -out apns-dev-key-noenc.pem
```

Enter pass phrase for apns-dev-key.pem:1234

```
cat apns-dev-cert.pem apns-dev-key-noenc.pem > apns-dev.pem
```

[image]

17) you have following certificate.

[image]

18) apns-dev.pem file send on server and it pass is 1234

19) for development you must use gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com server.
and distribution you can use gateway.push.apple.com server.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what does mean **'send .pem file on server'**. I'll have to generate push notifications from an Apache server using php. Do I have to put this file in my server directory and reference it from my php code?

Answer (score 10):

For **

- **Production Push Notification**

**

I took reference from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253261/4720315)

To enable Push Notification for your iOS app, you will need to create and upload the Apple Push Notification Certificate (.pem file) to us so we will be able to connect to Apple Push Server on your behalf.

(Updated version with updated screen shots Here http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/)

**Step 1:** Login to iOS Provisioning Portal, click "Certificates" on the left navigation bar. Then, click "+" button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 2:** Select Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production) option under Distribution section, then click "Continue" button.
[image]

**Step 3:** Select the App ID you want to use for your BYO app (How to Create An App ID), then click "Continue" to go to next step.

[image]

**Step 4:** Follow the steps "About Creating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)" to create a Certificate Signing Request.
[image]

To supplement the instruction provided by Apple. Here are some of the additional screenshots to assist you to complete the required steps:

**Step 4 Supplementary Screenshot 1**: Navigate to Certificate Assistant of Keychain Access on your Mac.

[image]

**Step 4 Supplementary Screenshot 2:** Fill in the Certificate Information. Click Continue.

[image]

**Step 5:** Upload the ".certSigningRequest" file which is generated in Step 4, then click "Generate" button.
[image]

**Step 6:** Click "Done" to finish the registration, the iOS Provisioning Portal Page will be refreshed that looks like the following screen:
[image]

Then Click "Download" button to download the certificate (.cer file) you've created just now. - Double click the downloaded file to install the certificate into Keychain Access on your Mac.

**Step 7:** On your Mac, go to "Keychain", look for the certificate you have just installed. If unsure which certificate is the correct one, it should start with "Apple Production IOS Push Services:" followed by your app's bundle ID.
[image]

**Step 8:** Expand the certificate, you should see the private key with either your name or your company name. Select both items by using the "Select" key on your keyboard, right click (or cmd-click if you use a single button mouse), choose "Export 2 items", like Below:
[image]

Then save the p12 file with name "pushcert.p12" to your Desktop - now you will be prompted to enter a password to protect it, you can either click Enter to skip the password or enter a password you desire.

**Step 9:** Now the most difficult part - open "Terminal" on your Mac, and run the following commands:

```
cd
cd Desktop
openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

**Step 10:** By using [this link(click here)](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/)

You can check weather the .PEM file is valid or not ---> if it's valid you will get success message with notification like:
[image]

For **

- **Development Push Notification**

**

Just Watch the following Youtube link [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HGPnuiLHM0) and enjoy..

Comment: In my case, just exporting the certificate (parent of private key) worked. Exporting both certificate and private key did not work.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a screenshot of what you have to select in step 3. It's not two certificates. It's a certificate + key.

[image]

Comment: after exporting key and certificate .p12 is genereated how i will generate .pem by using terminal

Comment: @Shakti I've never tried it myself, but did you try `openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out CertificateName.pem -nodes`?

Comment: yes i tried by importing both certificate and key .once i got mypushdev.p12 cerificate then i open terminal and wrote  this code  openssl pkcs12 -in mypushdev.p12 -out mypushdev.pem -nodes.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a much more simple solution. Just use [Certifire](http://certifire.io).
[Certifire](http://certifire.io) is a macOS application that generates Apple Push Notification Certificates with just one click in a couple of seconds.

Here are the steps:
1. Download the app.
2. Log in using your Apple Developer Account credentials.
3. Choose the App-ID
4. Click "Generate" button
5. You're done!

You will get APN certificates in .pem format as well as in .p12 format. 
Even more, you will get also combined .pem and .p12 too (key+cert)!
Much more, you will get no-passphrase versions of all these certificates also!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is awesome ! ! !

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the @Nitin's very well described answer. After creating the pem, you can validate it with the 
`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert MyKey.pem -key MyKey.pem`
where MyKey is the name of your pem file.

Replace the gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com with gateway.push.apple.com, to connect to the live APNS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your APNs certificate and click on export. This will generate the .p12 certificate on desktop
2. open terminal cd desktop and convert .p12 into .pem using following command

   openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes -clcerts

   [image: as shown in picture]