# Generate .pem file used to set up Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pem

I tried and tried to generate a .pem file, every time generating certificates from the client's account and then generating the .pem file using the terminal, but it's of no use. Can anyone give a step-by-step procedure?

Answer (score 968, accepted):

To enable Push Notification for your iOS app, you will need to create and upload the Apple Push Notification Certificate (.pem file) to us so we will be able to connect to Apple Push Server on your behalf.

(***[Updated version with updated screen shots Here](http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/)***)

Step 1: Login to iOS Provisioning Portal, click "Certificates" on the left navigation bar. Then, click "+" button.

[image]

Step 2: Select Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production) option under Distribution section, then click "Continue" button.

[image]

Step 3: Select the App ID you want to use for your BYO app (How to Create An App ID), then click "Continue" to go to next step.

[image]

Step 4: Follow the steps "About Creating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)" to create a Certificate Signing Request.

[image]

To supplement the instruction provided by Apple. Here are some of the additional screenshots to assist you to complete the required steps:

Step 4 Supplementary Screenshot 1: Navigate to Certificate Assistant of Keychain Access on your Mac.

[image]

Step 4 Supplementary Screenshot 2: Fill in the Certificate Information. Click Continue.

[image]

Step 5: Upload the ".certSigningRequest" file which is generated in Step 4, then click "Generate" button.

[image]

Step 6: Click "Done" to finish the registration, the iOS Provisioning Portal Page will be refreshed that looks like the following screen:

[image]

Then Click "Download" button to download the certificate (.cer file) you've created just now. - Double click the downloaded file to install the certificate into Keychain Access on your Mac.

Step 7: On your Mac, go to "Keychain", look for the certificate you have just installed. If unsure which certificate is the correct one, it should start with "Apple Production IOS Push Services:" followed by your app's bundle ID.

[image]

Step 8: Expand the certificate, you should see the private key with either your name or your company name. Select both items by using the "Select" key on your keyboard, right click (or cmd-click if you use a single button mouse), choose "Export 2 items", like Below:

[image]

Then save the p12 file with name "pushcert.p12" to your Desktop - now you will be prompted to enter a password to protect it, you can either click Enter to skip the password or enter a password you desire.

Step 9: Now the most difficult part - open "Terminal" on your Mac, and run the following commands:

```
cd
cd Desktop
openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

If anyone facing issues with the above code, use:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -legacy -nodes
```

Step 10: Remove pushcert.p12 from Desktop to avoid mis-uploading it to Build Your Own area. Open "Terminal" on your Mac, and run the following commands:

```
cd
cd Desktop
rm pushcert.p12
```

Step 11 - NEW AWS UPDATE: Create new `pushcert.p12` to submit to AWS SNS. Double click on the new `pushcert.pem`, then export the one highlighed on the green only.

[image]
Credit: [AWS new update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099233/trouble-with-aws-sns-setup-with-ios-push-notifications-certificate-type-not-sup)

Now you have successfully created an Apple Push Notification Certificate (.p12 file)! You will need to upload this file to our Build Your Own area later on. :)

Comment: Looks like this you can now export straight from Keychain to a PEM file (steps 8-10).

Comment: can I reproduce these steps for development certification?

Comment: Would it be possible to write a script for this for all certs matching a certain application id com.xx..., we have only 10 now, but could grow rapidly.

Comment: What is the "Build Your Own" area and why do we have to upload the pem file to it?

Comment: I'm getting a stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused). This is why I'm asking, because I probably forgot to upload the pem file to the "Build Your Own" area.

Comment: Images are not loading. Is it only for me?

Comment: great. Can you show how to derive both key.pem and cert.pem from the same statement? I'm pretty sure it's something like openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -nodes -clcerts. Thanks

Comment: Simply the best, most thorough answer to this question I have ever found.

Comment: How to i get passphrase?

Comment: I'm getting PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line when I try to use this.

Comment: You should not export both keys - Apple will reject the request. Just export the certificate and leave the private key

Comment: why do all these answers across the internet ignore the real question continually asked about what the 'Build Your Own' is? Where do you upload this PEM if using Xcode?

Comment: In my case, I needed to create two pem files from p12 cert.
Just export cert and key file respectively in keychain access instead of export 2 items together. But this answer is definitely awesome!

Comment: Our previous .cer expired so a colleague generated a new one, but we still don't know how, he generated it without an RSA key, so the .pem was incomplete too, our notification script was incapable of handling it. This answer helped me generate a new one and now everything's working. Anyone got an idea on how this .cer was generated without a key ?

Comment: Very good walkthrough. But you lost me at the "Select both items by using the "Select" key on your keyboard" part :)

Answer (score 82):

There's much simpler solution today — [*pem*](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/). This tool makes life much easier.

For example, to generate or renew your push notification certificate just enter:

```bash
fastlane pem
```

and it's done in under a minute. In case you need a sandbox certificate, enter:

```bash
fastlane pem --development
```

And that's pretty it.

Comment: And there is not only PEM. The entire fastlane tool is absolutelly brilliant

Comment: Is it also available for non-apple systems?

Comment: @KrauseFx, if I do generate it via pem, how do I get it show here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/? I find this quite useful to see the latest expiry date etc? Is this something that happens automatically?

Comment: I'm sorry for a rather late question on this awesome answer. But, can you please tell me what should I do after I create these certs with pem? Do I need to update something within the app or on iTunes Connect?

Comment: @IonicBurger Yeah this happens automatically

Comment: @Nikola No action on iTunes Connect required, you can use that pem file right away

Comment: @mikejd we dont need to specify which p12 should be used for pem ?

Comment: This answer does not provide enough (any) details on how to do this and/or how to extract PEM files from P12 exports.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ cd Desktop
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem
```

Comment: Does this work? I made a PEM file on windows 10 using this method, but I got an "Unable to connect to 'ssl:\/\/gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" when I use the generated pem to send push notifications.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks! to all above answers. 
I hope you have a .p12 file. Now, open terminal write following command. Set terminal to the path where you have put .12 file.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in yourCertifcate.p12 -out pemAPNSCert.pem -nodes
Enter Import Password: <Just enter your certificate password>
MAC verified OK
```

Now your **.pem** file is generated.

**Verify .pem file**
First, open the .pem in a text editor to view its content. The certificate content should be in format as shown below. Make sure the pem file contains both Certificate content(from BEGIN CERTIFICATE to END CERTIFICATE) as well as Certificate Private Key (from BEGIN PRIVATE KEY to END PRIVATE KEY) :

```
> Bag Attributes
>     friendlyName: Apple Push Services:<Bundle ID>
>     localKeyID: <> subject=<>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> 
> <Certificate Content>
> 
> -----END CERTIFICATE----- Bag Attributes
>     friendlyName: <>
>     localKeyID: <> Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> 
> <Certificate Private Key>
> 
> -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Also, you check the validity of the certificate by going to SSLShopper [Certificate Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html) and paste the Certificate Content (from BEGIN CERTIFICATE to END CERTIFICATE) to get all the info about the certificate as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gurjinder for the answer, only this solution worked for me. Every other solution gave me error "unknown option '–clcerts'" in terminal. You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

Apple have changed the name of the certificate that is issued. You can now use the same certificate for both development and production. While you can still request a development only certificate you can no longer request a production only certificate.

[image: please see below screnshot]

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple after exporting the Cert.p12 and key.p12,
Please find below command for the generating 'apns' .pem file.

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

```
command to create apns-dev.pem from Cert.pem and Key.pem
     

openssl rsa -in Key.pem -out apns-dev-key-noenc.pem
     

cat Cert.pem apns-dev-key-noenc.pem > apns-dev.pem
```

Above command is useful for both Sandbox and Production.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Troubleshooting Push Certificate Problems](https://thenotificationsbook.com/2018/08/28/troubleshooting-push-certificate-problems/)

> The SSL certificate available in your Apple Developer Program account contains a public key but not a private key. The private key exists only on the Mac that created the Certificate Signing Request uploaded to Apple. Both the public and private keys are necessary to export the Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM) file.

Chances are the reason you can't export a working PEM from the certificate provided by the client is that you do not have the private key. The certificate contains the public key, while the private key probably only exists on the Mac that created the original CSR.

You can either:

1. Try to get the private key from the Mac that originally created the CSR. Exporting the PEM can be done from that Mac or you can copy the private key to another Mac.

or

2. Create a new CSR, new SSL certificate, and this time back up the private key.

Answer (score 0):

## 2023

Newest way to create and download certificate for push notification and to export it into `.p12` and `.pem`:

## Downloading certificate to your machine

1. Login to your account on Apple Developer portal and select “Certificates”
2. Click “+” and select “Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)” and select “Continue”
3. Choose your app and select “Continue”
4. Upload your Certificate Signing Request (.csr), select “Continue” and then “Download”

## Saving it into Keychain

5. Double click on the newly downloaded .cer file and it will be automatically saved into your Keychain. Keychain will then open and show the list of your certificates.

## Getting .p12 file

6. Find the certificate, right click on it and select “Export…” and save it to Desktop. It will ask you to put a password to protect it, and it is optional, you don’t actually need it.

## Converting .p12 into .pem

1. Open Terminal and navigate to your .p12 destination
2. Use the command below and change “certificateName” into the name of the certificate and press Enter
3. It will ask for password you entered at step 6, type it and press Enter. If you didn’t provide a password at step 6, just press Enter and you will have .pem file saved at the same location where you saved your .p12.

`openssl pkcs12 -in certificateName.p12 -out certificateName.pem -nodes -clcerts`