# PyAPN right way to create PEM files

Tags: python, python-2.7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pyopenssl

I know this might be due to lack of better knowledge, but I seem not to be able to get this running. 
What is the right way as of today how to create the correct certificates / `pem` files for `PyAPN`? There are so many instructions at different dates that report different approaches - I am confused.

I exported the Apple push certificate and the private key into `cert.p12` and `key.p12` respectively on my mac. Then I ran the commands below and uploaded them to my server.

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out key.pem -in key.p12 
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem -in cert.p12
```

Here's my modified `apns-send.py`:

```
certificate_file = '/path/to/apnsCerts/cert.pem'
key_file = '/path/to/apnsCerts/key.pem'`
```

I try:

```
./apns-send.py -p fc0112d3936f738d9d4c197c50dbf80304ab13fca4ab19d539ecacf65ce58b34 -m 'Hello World'
```

Yet it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./apns-send.py", line 45, in <module>
    apns.gateway_server.send_notification(options.push_token, payload)
  File "/buyo/push/ios/apns.py", line 543, in send_notification
    self.write(self._get_notification(token_hex, payload))
  File "/buyo/push/ios/apns.py", line 267, in write
    return self._connection().write(string)
  File "/buyo/push/ios/apns.py", line 248, in _connection
    self._connect()
  File "/buyo/push/ios/apns.py", line 224, in _connect
    self._ssl = wrap_socket(self._socket, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in __init__
    ciphers)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions where it could fail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some googling and trial and errors I finally have gotten through to get a send confirmation `Sent push message to APNS gateway` from `PyAPNs`.

Here are the steps how I had to adjust my `pem` files.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys 
openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12  -out key.pem -nocerts  
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out keyNoPasswd.pem

cat keyNoPasswd.pem > mergedPushCertificate.pem
cat cert.pem >> mergedPushCertificate.pem
```

Use `mergedPushCertificate.pem` as certificate and key in PyAPNs.
Based on https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server/issues/6