# Apple Push notifications for distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In my app I am using Apple push notifications. I followed [Raywenderlich development tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). I am able to send and receive push notifications, but this is for development only. Now i want to submit my app at app store. I need an easy tutorial like the above for (APNS)distribution. Please help me. 
Thanks. I am using ios7 and xcode 5.

Comment: Here is the link that will surely help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification/21253261#21253261

Comment: already u have the SSL distribution certificate, if yes i tell the some simple stepsm otherwise create the SSL distribution certificate in developer site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find for following lines in simplepush.php

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

and replace it with following

```
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

Make sure you have generated the certificate and key for production as well

Answer (score 0):

You must also change the certificate that is used for the APNS connection when you change the url.

What I do in my apps is allow for connections to either server (sandbox or production).  In my server that sends APNS to Apple, I check to see if the notification is a development or a production request, and direct it to the appropriate url, using the right certificate.

I have an extra column in my table that I use to store APNS subscriptions to indicate whether this is a development subscription and should use the development (sandbox) certificate.

```
id, 
DeviceToken, 
DeviceID --identifierForVendor, 
NetworkID, 
Application, 
AddedOn, 
Active, 
Dev, 
BadgeCount
```

Then you can just do the logic in your APNS server app and decide which URL and which cert to use.

Like iDeveloper said,
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
or
sl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195