# APNs cerificate distrubution

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

Can i distribute my APNs certificate and key to many people and all those peoples servers can send notification to my iOS app on device. I have the device token etc. I need to know is there any limitations on this process

Comment: You need to generate a PEM file from APNs and you can distribute use that pem file to send motifications from any server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate *.pem* certificate from your APNs for production as well as development. You can find steps to do so [here in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification) and here in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)

[image]
Once you have valid .pem certificate you can use it from any server . There is no limitation in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) for using this but ofcourse , that pem certificate will work for sending notification to your app only .

Hope this helps.