# push notification - recreate pem from existing

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pem, recreate

starting from the steps reported in this post: 
[Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)

is it possible to recreate the apsn-server.pem for production server starting from the point 7?

Comment: then u were first used in the apns for developer profile

Comment: i have both, development works, production no. I would to recreate the pem, or better, I done it but it didn't works

Comment: if u r using production u need to create the another pem

Comment: but I supposed I can start from actual production certificate, that have push notifications enabled. but It's what I have done until today, but it doesn't work. 
is it possible that I have to start from scratch, creating a new Distribution certificate?