# Push notification is not working when I transfer app to other account

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have transfered the app after I released new version push notification is not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Too little information to diagnose, but I think you have to create another Production APNS certificate for your server.

Comment: Would strongly recommend including some more information to prevent being flagged/closed.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the problem description is very lacking I think that the solution is very obvious: the APNS certificate is strongly linked to the Apple Member account certificates/provisioning files. If they don't match, the push won't come through.

That means, you have to sign your app with the same provisioning file (with the same bundle id) you've signed the old app with.

If you don't have the access to the old provisioning file's certificates, you have to create a new APNS certificate.

[StackOverflow question explaining setting up APNS certs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)

or

[certs tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925)

Answer (score 1):

Either the original account owner has invalidated the original push notification certificate, or you have an error in your server unrelated to the transfer process.

I advice you to

1. Create a new push certificate.
2. Test that it works by sending a notification from a desktop app like [APNS Pusher](https://github.com/KnuffApp/Knuff).
3. Update the push certificate in your server.