# Invalid .p12 file on Pushwoosh

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, pushwoosh

In Keychain Access -> Keys, I only see 2 keys that were generated by the Certficate Signing Request. And these keys are a single row which do not have any certificates under them.

[image: Screenshot Keychain Acesss]

In the Pushwoosh IOS integration guide it shows the APNS certifcate under the key's row, but for me it doesn't.

And on exporting the private key as a p12 file, Pushwoosh says its invalid.

How do I create a valid p12 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faces this problem earlier

Try with this:"[Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)"

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you skipped section 3.5 of the [iOS configuration guide](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/apns-configuration:):

> Download the certificate and double-click on it to install it in the Keychain Access application (see Figure 13). This is the SSL certificate that will be used by Pushwoosh so that it can contact the APNs to send push notifications to your applications. Now you need to export the certificate.

Make sure your APNS certificate will appear in "My Certificates" section.