# Swift Push Notifications

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a newb question. I am a little confused with push notifications.

I am working with push notifications between iOS and a PC app. Apparently the PC needs one of the certs or something in order to send push notifications. I remember setting up several things in developer.apple.com. Like bundle id, provisioning profile, and cert. which do I need on the PC side to send push notifications to the iOS device?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to generate PEM file to use it in server side :-
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)
Secondly prepare your server :-
from [here](http://www.easyapns.com/php-source)