# Address of Apple development push notification server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is server `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` the correct development APN server?

I found this address in back-end sources and wondering hence Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) contains another address: `api.development.push.apple.com:443`.

Comment: yes 2195 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the useful CLI utility source code of [Houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) by [Mattt Thompson](https://twitter.com/mattt):

```
APPLE_PRODUCTION_GATEWAY_URI = "apn://gateway.push.apple.com:2195"
APPLE_PRODUCTION_FEEDBACK_URI = "apn://feedback.push.apple.com:2196"
APPLE_DEVELOPMENT_GATEWAY_URI = "apn://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195"
APPLE_DEVELOPMENT_FEEDBACK_URI = "apn://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196"
```

Further references can be found [here](https://github.com/nomad/houston/blob/master/lib/houston/client.rb).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Can I test ability to receive push notifications in app with Houston?

Comment: Of course! I use it every day and It is an excellent utility.
Just install the nomad-cli by typing:
    `gem install nomad-cli`
and send your push with
    `apn push "<token>" -c /path/to/apple_push_notification.pem -m "Test"`

Comment: Thanks! `.pem` file is a push notifications certificate for back-end?

Comment: Yes, a `.pem` file is a converted Apple `.p12` certificate downloaded from `developer.apple.com` and then exported from your Mac's keychain. You can follow this guide to generate it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification

Comment: If you find my information correct and did solve your question please mark it as resolved. It could help to build my reputation on S.O.
Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Comment: JP_Mob's answers were valuable as well! So I can not tick your answer as more valuable in honour to JP_Mob. Peace to you all guys! Thanks!

Comment: Ok no problem, you decide. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

TCP port 443: For a fallback on Wi-Fi only, when devices can't reach APNs on port 5223
TCP port 2195: For sending notifications to APNs

Check below link for details.
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203609

Comment: Thank you! I do not receive notifications from dev server (remote) instead from local one. How can I found the core of problem? Is there a possibility to know correctness of settings of certificates on dev server? Or correctness of provisioning profiles state?

Comment: just check your backend that should be correct and if you are using developer profile use sandbox APNS on server,Also check server side they should get correct device token.