# Certificates and provisions for iOS build in {N}

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, nativescript, firebase-cloud-messaging, telerik-appbuilder

I have followed steps mentioned at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253261/6449750) for creating development certificate and provision profile. I am trying to implement FCM and running **Nativescript** application in real device. Following are the steps I have followed to build project :

1. Imported provision with `appbuilder provision import path/to/provision`
2. Installed development certificate in the key-chain.
3. Exported .p12 file and saved to local disk.
4. Imported certificate with `appbuilder certificate import path/to/p12/cert`
5. Creating build with `appbuilder build ios --provision "XXXX" --certificate "XXXX"`

But it does give me error

> Certificate is not included in provision's certificates

Please correct me if i did anything wrong. Do suggest some solution if you have been through this as i am new to this stuff and Nativescript.

P.S. I also tried giving provision to appbuilder site it also shows some warning in certificate field [image]

Here is **APNS permission**

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

---

As mentioned by @Eddy Verbruggen (Author [NativeScript Firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase))

> I asked Telerik after this email and they confirmed it's a bug in their browser client and hope to have it fixed soon. They created a ticket for it.

Comment: Check your private key within that certificate in your Keychain - whether it's imported properly

Comment: Tried importing twice and it doesn't give error while importing so i guess its working fine. Is there any way to confirm ?

Comment: I am doing this stuff with CLI. I am not using xCode as there is no platform folder with appBuilder project.

Comment: In that case i have many certificates for development and distribution. How can i make sure that profile required by provision is present ?

Comment: I am afraid its not present. what should be next step ? Present certificates are distribution also from other project.

Comment: Importing certificate and p12 file is not doing that thing, I tried.

Comment: OK, the last possible option is to check whether your Provisioning profiles are updated to new (newer) Certificate. It looks like your Cert is newer and PPs were not updated yet. You should go to developer account and check PPs, so there is no yellow triangle warning, that is invalid.

Comment: I am creating PP every time a new certificate is generated.

Comment: But make sure, the cert that is included within the Profile corresponds.

Comment: Yes that is what error saying. How can i make sure that cert. is included in the profile ?

Comment: Open a PPs in your Developer account, find appropriate Profile and open it by clicking on it. Check [which cert](http://pasteboard.co/beDu77C8P.png) is included:

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: Nop but thanks anyways. Still don't understand what is missing when I created certificate.

Comment: Have checked that profile within developer account? You haven't confirmed it yet.

Comment: Actually it's a Team account so there are lots of profiles so selected all developers an tried that PP but same error.

Comment: I got this working with CLI (`tns`) but issue still persist with `appbuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

In tutorial he didn't check push notification in app id please ensure that in your app id you enabled Push notification as screenshot and has green circle

[image]

Comment: Yes it has green circle i double checked that.

Comment: Same certificate and provision works if i use it with Nativescript project but doesn't work with appBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

> Certificate is not included in provision's certificates

This error message is usually generated when there are no matching public keys in the *.mobileprovision* profile with the cryptographic identity that you use.

You can validate that the *.mobileprovison* is bind to this particular certificate by extracting the *.p12* public key and search for a match under the `<key>DeveloperCertificates</key>` array in the *.mobileprovison*'s xml portion.

You could extract the public key from the .p12 cryptographic identity by using `openssl`.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <path_to_.p12> -clcerts -nokeys -out <path_to_resulting_public_key.pem> && cat <path_to_resulting_public_key.pem>
```

Once you know the public key, verify that it is listed under the `<key>DeveloperCertificates</key>` in your *.mobileprovison* file. You can do this by either running the command below or simply open *.mobileprovision* with text editor such as notepad++

```
security cms -D -i <path_to_.mobileprovision> | grep -f <path_to_resulting_public_key.pem>
```

I'd also recommend to delete all .mobileprovision files and certificates from your appbuilder profile and then re-import the items in question.
You can do this by running the following commands:

```
appbuilder certificate // List certificates 
appbuilder certificate remove <name or index> // Delete cerificates
appbuilder provision // List provisions
appbuilder provision remove <provision_id> // Delete provisions 
appbuilder provision remove <provision_id> // Delete provisions 
appbuilder provision import path/to/provision
appbuilder certificate import path/to/p12/cert
```

**EDIT:**
NOTE: You might also find interesting the following {N} plugin - https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin

Steps on how to generate a APNS certificate and a mobileprovision file.

- Verify that you have created and added a pair of matching certificate and provisioning profile in AppBuilder. For more information about certificates and provisioning profiles, see [Configuring Code Signing for iOS Apps](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps).
- Verify that the App ID in the provisioning profile is enabled for push notifications. In the [Identifiers section in the iOS Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action), select your identifier from the list and review the enabled services. If needed, click Edit and enable the missing functionality. If you modify an existing App ID, make sure to recreate the matching provisioning profile and import it into AppBuilder.
- Verify that you have set the proper App ID for your application in the Project Properties dialog.
- Verify that you have created an Apple Push Notification service SSL certificate in the [Certificates section in the iOS Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action) and added it in AppBuilder.
- Verify that the type of the Apple Push Notification service SSL certificate matches the type of your certificate and provisioning profile for code signing your app. For example, both should be for development or for production.
- Verify that you have exported the P12 file for the Apple Push Notification service SSL cryptographic identity. For more information about how to export cryptographic identities from AppBuilder, see [Export a Cryptographic Identity](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/export-identity).

Comment: I think its not listed as i tried some of line and find in data block. Can you help me with how to generate profile with matching .pem file ?

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: About the plugin you referenced, its working fine if i don't have to navigate to different pages. But i have requirement where based on notification type and payload i have to navigate. This plugin don' t provide application state so that i can know if app is in foreground then i don't have to navigate and if app is in background and i click on notification then app should open particular page.