# Push Notification for IOS not working

Tags: ios, push-notification

We created the certificate .p12 using the Private Key only option. We tried push notification through MAC and its working fine. I used the below code which is not giving any error but iPhone is not getting any notification. In this Helper is my class to write log to file.

```
public void PushNotificationIOS(string message, string registrationKey, int type)
    {
        string deviceID = registrationKey; 
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IosPort"]); //2195;
        string hostname = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];//"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
        string certPath = string.Empty;
        certPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePath"] + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateName"];//"~/Content/PushCertificateNew.p12";            
        string certificatePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(certPath);
        string certPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"];
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), certPassword);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helper.WriteLog("sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient : TLS  " + ex.Message);
            }

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)32);
            writer.Write(StringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
            String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":0,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
            byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            writer.Write(b1);
            writer.Flush();
            byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            sslStream.Write(array);
            sslStream.Flush();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            Helper.WriteLog("PushNotificationIOS catch  I :" + ex.Message);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helper.WriteLog("PushNotificationIOS catch  II :" + e.Message);
            client.Close();
        }

    }
```

Can anyone tell us how to trace the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in .p12 creation process from KeyChain.

You can select the cert, and open the arrow to also select the private key and export them together as a **.p12** file from Keychain Access.

[image]

From that you can generate **.pem** file using below command in terminal

```
cd
cd Desktop
openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification) for details info

Comment: If we make certificate like this than it gives an error "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" on "sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);". I find a solution to create certificate using private key only if we are doing from c#. We can use both if we are doing coding in PHP.

Comment: umm ok...I m trying to trace your issue

Comment: You found anything?

Comment: I am still didn't find the solution for this issue.