# Trouble with AWS SNS setup with IOS Push Notifications (Certificate type not supported)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I am trying to set up SNS push notifications with ios and after following a few tutorials I get this error message. I am not sure what "type" of certificate I am currently using that is not currently supported or how to go about providing a "better" one. Any help is appreciated.

tried the aws tutorial and on step 4 (Step 4: Verify the Certificate and App Private Key) I get an error:

error setting private key
9940:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:406:

and

http://www.adventuresofanentrepreneur.net/creating-a-mobile-appsgames-company/setting-up-aws-sns-to-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices

where I get the confusing " You provided a certificate of type that is not currently supported."

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hodsk.png)

Answer (score 16):

Don't select the private key to export .p12 certificate.[image]
Click on the certificate and export it to .p12 certificate. I came across the same error " You provided a certificate of type that is not currently supported" When I tried to create application in AWS SNS. I observed the issue is with exporting certificate.

Comment: This really solves my problem. The old and popular answers for this was saying that we have to export both of them as a `.p12` file.