# Ionic push notifications

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am trying to extend my app with a push service.
Looking through the web I found several ionic examples, yet have not been able to wrap my head around it.

Here's my goal:

My server should send a push notification about every 3 hours to each individual user to update them on their individual parameters.

Hence, I need a server solution that targets the package to each individual.
On the client side I thought of using

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

I already obtained apple push certificates but am not sure how to use them...
Any help is welcome!

Comment: What's is your sever framework ?? is it Laravel, .NET, NodeJS ??

Comment: I thought of using NodeJS.

Comment: you can see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushserver to configure your server. In this code you should provide your apple push certificates and your GCM API-Key.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot. How can I send push messages to individual users? How do I get their tokens automatically? Every user will receive an individual message.

Answer (score 1):

[$cordovaPushV5](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/) is the latest version & works perfectly. Get your SENDER_ID by registering [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add)

Comment: Thanks! How do I get user tokens automatically? Every user will receive an individual message.

Comment: What is the SENDER_ID in `$cordovaPushV5` for Apple?

Comment: Every user's device id will get registered to the API, having similar SENDER_ID, however for iOS there is alot of certificates stuff to be done!

Comment: Thank you Muhammad! I found this nice example https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample , do you think it is compatible with `$cordovaPushV5`?

Comment: No idea about it, however it looks like a wrapper, which is deep down also using cordova!

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement analysis I would recommend to use Ionic's push from Ionic Cloud API with matchless compatibility across all platform you can find you more about it here

[Ionic Push Notification Docs](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/)

More over it provides online portal for certificate configuration area minimal onboard configuration required extending the functionality it also provides online portal for sending out push to your devices along with Restful API services for server utilization.

For Tokens : Ionic will be responsible of generating token all you need to do is save that token on your localdb for future reference to send push notification to targeted device. Tokens will be generated one time only upon first run of the application. (Token needs to be renewed upon New install / Update)

Comment: Thanks Syed, but I am affraid this this is too high level. I need to automate my push notifications so that they are generated by an interface that connects my user DB and the push engine. I do not find an API for the `Ionic Push` that would automate that?

Comment: No API was for Ionic Push 1, Ionic Push 2 has the RESTful API you mentioned. Looking into it.

Comment: Hi El kindly refer to this link https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#sending-pushes

Answer (score 0):

At first Install following  Plugin under your project

cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Download following code from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-b-DfCLwKdREkwZFdYVEhYWXM

Then merge code in your app.js and after that run your application in iphone and check in console device if you are getting token or not, if device token is showing then move on to next step.

Then you can store device token in database when user login or register.

Then enter your [.pem] file location and pass phrase in  [db.class.php]

Then enter device token in [sendIphonenotification.php] file

Then execute [sendIphonenotification.php] file and check your iphone you will get a notification.

Also, if you face any issue in generating .pem file and passphrase then you can follow this link: [Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)