# Push Notification (APNS) not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I used development provisioning profile for my build in it push notifications working fine but at the time when I used distribution provisioning It will not work. I did'n get any notification at foreground and background.

Comment: did you follow all steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253261/6898523 ? if yes, delete the derived data, re-select the provisioning profile in build settings and delete the app from device and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting Dev Push notification, its means you know how to start APNS life cycle. try your Push on https://pushtry.com/ . it'll provide you the real bug.

But i'm hoping that you backend developer still sending push to

**gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com and port TCP 2195**.

Please ask him to send it on

**gateway.push.apple.com and port TCP 2195**

and if it's clear already, then re-create your certificates.

Comment: after change gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com to gateway.push.apple.com  error showing Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): 0 on pushtry

Comment: now its working there is backend issue. they set wrong password.. Thanks.