# Apple wallet pass type ID

Tags: wallet

The `passTypeIdentifier` or `teamIdentifier` provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.

I am creating new Pass type ID in apple developer account using my pass type ID but, I was created pass type ID after I also create certificate then install in keychain,

Now, I export 2 file and save `.p12` file at my folder, after that I open terminal and extract with `.p12` file to `.pem` file and upload to my AWS server

Now, I run this code and try to download in iPhone safari browser but not able to download it.

After I try to debug via Xcode using Console and I figure out like

> The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.

Comment: You haven’t included any code.  Also, have you included the WWDR certificate?

Comment: Ya, I was configure previous Generic pass,

Comment: Can you tell me like once I  generate .pem file using that .p12 in (terminal) command like that
“openssl pkcs12 -in Certificate.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts“

Now, once I generate .pem file need to verify anywhere in Apple developer account

Comment: Can you post a link to a pass bundle?  I don’t think that the error relates to the way you processed the certificates.  More likely the team name or cert name does not match, or you are not including the WWDR certificate.  If you cannot post a link to a pass, then post the pass.json and the base64 encoded signature bytes (`cat signature | base64`).

Comment: using Xcode Console I figure out like .pem is the issues, I am sure that .p12 is proper with my bundle

Comment: If I could see your signature bytes, I could tell you whether or not you have converted it correctly.

Comment: Can you tell me where i have to include WWDR?

Comment: It needs to be included in the chain when you sign the pass.  You haven't stated what language you are coding in.  It's impossible to help you without seeing the code you are using to sign the pass.

Comment: I need to clarify one thing my generic pass is working with .p12 and .pem file using WWDR certificate, but when I'm trying with loyalty pass I am getting "passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match"

Comment: With no idea of what you are doing (no code, no output, not even a description of the steps you are taking to compile the pass), it’s impossible to help you.

Comment: You say _"Now, I run this code"_ - what code are you running? Seeing the pass or seeing your code, this could have been instantly resolved.

Comment: I am using this link for generate .pem file
Here is link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-set-up-apple-push-notifications

Comment: 1. In Apple site create pass type id from identifier: com.pass.yourname.passname
2. Upload CSR file to identifier with getting CSR file from my keychain
3. After I download certificate like pass.cer file
4. Double click to that pass and install to my keychain
5. In Keychain - Login - Certificate option select my identifier
6. Export 2 items and save certificate.p12 file in your disk
7. After open Terminal and go with your folder path
8. Then I am using this command to generate .pem file 
Command like : openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts

Comment: I don’t know how many different ways I cans say this - but the issue isn’t with your certificate.  How are you signing the .pkpass bundle?  What code or tool are you using? Either the signature that this code is generating is invalid or the pass.json contains an incorrect team identifier it pass type id.

Comment: Okay, Let me try to check pass.json contains an correct team identifier or not,

Comment: Did you find the issue @NikhilJobanputra I'm experimenting the same error. In my case I'm using the singpass tool from Apple to generate the .pkpass as a first step

Comment: May i know, what exactly error comes, can you please share error here?