# xcode7.2 process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry to ask this. I Already googled it a lot and i followed all the solution but still i am facing same issue . That's the reason only i am posting this question:

I am trying to launch my app on device. It is launching successfully on the simulator.

- List item
- I use 9.2 SDK
- Xcode 7.2
- And the device is a 9.2 iPhone 6 plus

I have tried:

1. Clean
2. Clean Build Folder
3. Deleting app
4. Disconnecting/Reconnecting device
5. Booting device
6. restarting Xcode
7. **Currently i am using a Distribution certificate(AdHoc Push notification) instead of Developer one**
8. I recreated
9. I removed all certificates from Xcode and i Download all and then i connected Device
10. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts - Remove my account
11. Go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...

    Select the Run Scheme

    Select the Info tab

    Make sure the settings are as follows:

    Build Configuration is set to "Debug"

    Debug Executable is checked

    Launch Automatically is checked
12. CLOSE ITUNES (itunes must be closed)

But still i am facing same issue.  Can you please help me out regarding this issue[image]

[image]

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22683419/5608661

Comment: Hi Sir, I already checked this link and i followed all the proper solutions also but still i am facing same issue that's the reason only i posted this question. Can you plz help me out.    And more over by using thos link i created AdHoc Production certificate:: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34634077/4720315

Comment: Any one would suggest the same thing. check your provisioning profile and pray it fixes. If it doesn't reiterate the steps you have enumerated till it is solved.

Comment: are you trying to use Distribution certificate to install on iPhone? You can't

Comment: The thing is i tried to create AdHoc Push notification certificate and then i tried to install this app in Device

Comment: Okay.. Follow this... Re-create push certificate, add it in app ID, then create provision profile and then try to install...

Comment: & if it is latest xcode 7.2, then re-start xcode after you download the provision profile... restart is MUST...

Comment: ThanQ.. @ Fahim Parkar

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using **Distribution certificate(AdHoc Push notification)** use **Developer profile**. And try it.

Comment: For testing purpose i changed the "Run" to use Release scheme and then forget to change back to Debug. This helped me.
Thanks

Comment: After replace the Certificate and Provision, delete the app from the device before new running.