# Push Notification in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, terminator

I need a  procedure for push notification in `objective-c.`

step by step

Where to write code notification request and ask for the key ?

I have already tried it but stuck at some point and don't know how to solve

I have tried this in terminator:

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pen-in cert.p12

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out key.pen -in key.p12

Openssl rsa  -in key.pem  -out key.unencrypted.pem

Cat cert.pem  key.pem >ck.pem
```

Comment: Please go through this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Follow below 3 commands step-by-step in terminal

In First, give your .cer file as input

**1) openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem**

In Second, give your .p12 file and input password 4-5 times

**2) openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in Certificates.p12**

In Third, generate your .pem file and give to the server side.

**3) cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ckBRIDriver.pem**

Answer (score 0):

No need to follow this long steps. Just execute this one line in terminal.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

pushcert.p12 <= This should be your APNS dev/prod .p12

[Reference from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055756/how-can-i-generate-pem-file-for-push-notifications-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, try with Google firebase, they provide excellent documentation for end to end workflow. You can also test your App with the help of Google console.

Steps are:

1. Integrate Firebase SDK
2. Generate development certificates from Apple developer account.
3. Upload your certificates and enter your App bundle ID.
4. Send a sample message from google console

Reference Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

p12 Certificates: https://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-distribution-certificate